# How to run jQuery before and after a pjax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

I'm currently using pjax and it works great but I need to run two jQuery functions, one before pjax loads the new url and one after the new url is loaded, how can I do this?

I have tried the following two variations but neither seem to work?

First attempt:

```
$("a").pjax("#main").live('click', function(){

    //Function Before Load  
    // Function After Load
})
```

Second attempt:

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function(){

    //Function Before Load  

    $(this).pjax("#main");

    //Function After Load   

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you try what's in the [docs](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events)?

Comment: @ChristianVarga I missed that part, thought the jQuery section finished after it moved on to server side.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As they says in their doc [here](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) `pjax` fires two events for what you need

> pjax will fire two events on the container you've asked it to load
>   your reponse body into:
>
> pjax:start - Fired when a pjax ajax request begins.
>
> pjax:end - Fired when a pjax ajax request ends.

And the code example for this

```
$('a.pjax').pjax('#main')
$('#main')
  .on('pjax:start', function() { //do what you want to do before start })
  .on('pjax:end',   function() { //after the request ends });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function(){

 $(this).pjax("#main");
 $('a.pjax').pjax('#main')
 $('#main').on('pjax:start', function() { /* your code before ajax load */ });
 $('#main').on('pjax:end',   function() { /* your code after ajax load */ });

  return false;
});
```